# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Django - how do I service worker?

Tags: javascript, django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

**Update from a place of mild understanding:**

I have read much about Service Workers and advanced the project I'm working on far past where it was when I wrote this.

The main issue I was exploring here (getting `firebase-messaging-sw.js` served from the root of the domain) was solved by the `ServiceWorkerView` below.

Fun fact: turns out that the reason to have `firebase-messaging-sw.js` served from the root of the domain is that the scope of a Service Worker's control is defined by the URL. So, while:

`http://whatever.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js` has control over everything,

`http://whatever.com/static/firebase-messaging-sw.js` only has control over everything under `/static/` (in this case, only the static resources served by Django). Even though the JS file is static, it needs to control pages outside that path.

[A good starting point for learning about Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/)

**Original Question:**

How do I get the FCM service worker (`firebase-messaging-sw.js`) to work in Django?

I'm using `django` with `fcm-django`.

How do I serve `firebase-messaging-sw.js` at the root?

Django serves static assets by default under the path “/static/“. Changing the STATIC_URL to “/“ makes `firebase-messaging-sw.js` available but nothing else is..

I tried a suggestion to put the following in my urls.py:

`url(r'^(?!/static/.*)(?P<path>.*\..*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/%(path)s'))`

While clearly a glorious use of regex magic, it turns out that the service worker can't be behind a redirect. (I guess this also has to do with the fun fact)

I wrote a view pointed to by an explicit URL in the urlconf. that works.

```
class ServiceWorkerView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'fcmtest/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
```

urls.py:

`path('firebase-messaging-sw.js', views.ServiceWorkerView.as_view(), name='service_worker')`

Now the url `http://localhost:8000/firebase-messaging-sw.js` serves up the javascript; however, Firebase complains that the content-type is `text/plain`

So I changed the view to:

```
class ServiceWorkerView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'fcmtest/firebase-messaging-sw.js', content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

And the error I get is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A
>   bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

My `firebase-messaging-sw.js` (note none of the console.log statements print):

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-messaging.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/init.js");

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBOb5gh1Lry84116M1uvAS_xnKtcWUoNlA",
    authDomain: "pyfcm-5f794.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pyfcm-5f794.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pyfcm-5f794",
    storageBucket: "pyfcm-5f794.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "813943398064"
};
console.log('in service worker - before initializeApp')
firebase.initializeApp(config);
console.log('in service worker - after initializeApp')

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log('in service worker - after firebase.messaging')

// if the app is in the background (user not on page)
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('in service worker - in setBackgroundMessageHandler')
    const title = "Hello World";
    const options = {
        body: payload.data.status
    }
    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});
```

and finally, my device registration page (I'm not sure how to run the javascript and then submit. form.submit() didn't work but that might be because of other things not working..?
(`fcm/fcmtest/templates/fcmtest/device_registration.html`):

```
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>FCM Device Registration</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBOb5gh1Lry84116M1uvAS_xnKtcWUoNlA",
    authDomain: "pyfcm-5f794.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pyfcm-5f794.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pyfcm-5f794",
    storageBucket: "pyfcm-5f794.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "813943398064"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <!--<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>-->
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <!--<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>-->
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <!--<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/init.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body>

<script>

function deviceRegistration() {
    console.log('in deviceRegistration()')
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    // public key generated in firebase console
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey("BMEoHrnzLq5WNeyahbSxJNTyS-44bXug2wetxAWVMLMSUIQE0dexhP4pJhcSA-ZlQlneHURmYQcnq9ofym_sStY");
    // console.log('{% static "firebase-messaging-sw.js" %}')
    console.log("/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
    // changed location passed to navigator.serviceWorker.register since I am no longer serving firebase-messaging.js from localhost/static/ (see that url hack)
    // navigator.serviceWorker.register('{% static "firebase-messaging-sw.js" %}')
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
    .then((registration) => {
        console.log('before messaging.useServiceWorker')
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
        console.log('after messaging.useServiceWorker')

        // Request permission and get token.....
        messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function(){
            console.log("Have Permission");
        })
        .then(function(token) {
            form = document.getElementById("registration_form");

            registration_token = messaging.getToken();
            form.registration_id = registration_token;

            var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") >= -1;
            if (isAndroid) {
                form.type = "android";
            } else {
                var isiOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
                if (isiOS) {
                    form.type = "ios";
                } else {
                    form.type = "web";
                }
            }

            //form.submit();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log("Permission denied");
        })
    });

    // request permission to send notifications
    messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function(){
            console.log("Have Permission");
        })
        .then(function(token) {
            form = document.getElementById("registration_form");

            registration_token = messaging.getToken();
            form.registration_id = registration_token;

            var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") >= -1;
            if (isAndroid) {
                form.type = "android";
            } else {
                var isiOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
                if (isiOS) {
                    form.type = "ios";
                } else {
                    form.type = "web";
                }
            }

            //form.submit();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log("Permission denied");
        })

    // if user is on the page then show message directly instead of a notification
    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log('payload: ', payload);
    });

}

</script>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}


<form id="registration_form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <input id="type" type="hidden" />
    <input id="user" type="hidden" value="{{ user.id }}" />
    <input id="registration_id" type="hidden" />
    <input id="btn_register" type="button" value="Register" onclick="deviceRegistration();" />
</form>

</body>
```

I tried adding a `manifest.json` as per instructions on
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

It is currently served from my static files and is linked in the registration and send pages

The errors in my console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A
>   bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
>
> A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
>
> firebase-messaging-sw.js:3 Uncaught
>
> > (anonymous) @ firebase-messaging-sw.js:3
>
> index.esm.js:1945 Uncaught (in promise)
>
> > Object
> >
> > > browserErrorMessage:
> > >
> > > > "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed"
> > >
> > > code:
> > >
> > > > "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
> > >
> > > message:
> > >
> > > > "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
> > >
> > > stack:
> > >
> > > > "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-messaging.js:1:34104"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of not being able to serve `firebase-messaging-sw.js` can be solved by creating a `ServiceWorkerView` to `GET` the file directly and hardcoding the `URLconf`.

fcm/fcmtest/views.py:

```
class ServiceWorkerView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'fcmtest/firebase-messaging-sw.js', content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

fcm/fcmtest/urls.py

```
app_name = 'fcmtest'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('firebase-messaging-sw.js', views.ServiceWorkerView.as_view(), name='service_worker')
]
```

The reason to serve `firebase-messaging-sw.js` from the root of the domain is that the scope of a Service Worker's control is defined by the URL path. Everything under the path the Service Worker is available at is under its control.

---

The `404` might be due to a javascript error in `device_registration.html`. `config` is referenced but has not been assigned to.

```
function deviceRegistration() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Also, it is not necessary (maybe even problematic) to do this with Firebase Cloud Messaging:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
.then((registration) => {
    messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
})
```

Instead, use `firebase.initializeApp(config);`

---

It might be a good idea to serve `manifest.json` at the root.

---

The issue with `form.submit()` is that the code to alter the elements in the form from the promise is incomplete. After debugging that it will work great.

Answer (score 1):

I like what Inversus has done because it will work in dev/test/prod. That being said, in production I have elected to let nginx serve the firebase-messaging-sw.js file . . .

```
    # Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) requires this file to be served from
    # your root directory
    location =/firebase-messaging-sw.js {
        root /home/ubuntu/yourpath/yourproject/FCM/;
    }
```